# Backup and restore my System

Tags: backup

Hello I would like to backup my system (aps,data,properties , desktop etc) in order to restore if i need it

I want a full backup . For example i know my android mobile to buck it up (the rom) and restore it any time with any change

Is it possible to do it this in Ubuntu ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Clonezilla for full disk/partition backups.  Has a lot more to it too.
http://clonezilla.org/downloads/alternative/iso-zip-files.php

Comment: With Clonzilla i can backup full my system ? apps,data,desktop screenn etc ? and then restore them anytime ?

Comment: Its a full disk cloning tool, like norton ghost, acronis true image and dd