# How to create a restoration point in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, backup, restore

I would like to know if there is a possible way of configuring or creating a restoration point in Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: Ubuntu does not have restoration points. Changes you make to settings, preferrences etc. as an user are saved in the user's home folder, and backed up with the default backup app. Possible duplicate of [Backup and restore my System](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66695/backup-and-restore-my-system)

Comment: There's something called [timeshift](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift). You could look at it: "Timeshift for Linux is an application that provides functionality similar to the System Restore feature in Windows and the Time Machine tool in Mac OS."

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Comment: THank you all @DKBose I did it with timeshift, looked like it worked